# Unable to extract 7z archive containing EXE/DLL file using SevenZipsharp

Tags: c#, .net, sevenzipsharp

Unable to extract using `.ExtractArchive(pathname)` method, for .EXE/.DLL Files, using sevenZipSharp dll (https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=sevenzipsharp), official 7zip.exe can extract same "EXE/DLL" files.

`.ExtractArchive(pathname)` works fine with file extensions other than EXE/DLL
The  sevenzipsharp library code gets stuck at

```
 var data = new PropVariant();
 _archive.GetProperty(index, ItemPropId.Path, ref data); --stuck here
```

no compression done , used with AES pswd

[image]

Comment: If you're reporting a bug, this isn't the place to do it.

Comment: @itsme86 i don't think its a bug , its the main feature of the library , which is not working for me . i have also disabled AV software.